# MissingPropertyException in Spock test

Tags: java, spring-boot, spock

I have problem with test written in groovy (using Spock as a framework). While I try fetch property in `then` block and then use it in interaction I receive `No such property: updatedValue for class: my.test.class.MyTestClass` on the interaction with event publisher. Can anyone tell why is that?

```
class MyTestClass extends Specification {


@Autowired
private MyClass sut

@Autowired
private MyClassRepository myClassRepository


@SpringBean
private EventPublisher eventPublisher = Mock()


def "Should do something"() {
    given:
    //some data
    def someId = "someId"
    def event = new SomeEventObject()

    when:
    sut.handle(event)

    then:
    def updatedValue = myClassRepository.findTestClass(someId)
    updatedTestClass.cash == 100

    1 * eventPublisher.publishEvent(new SomeNextEvent(updatedValue))
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are encountering a side-effect of Spock's magic.

Your method basically gets transformed to this:

```
public void $spock_feature_0_0() {
        org.spockframework.runtime.ErrorCollector $spock_errorCollector = org.spockframework.runtime.ErrorRethrower.INSTANCE
        org.spockframework.runtime.ValueRecorder $spock_valueRecorder = new org.spockframework.runtime.ValueRecorder()
        java.lang.Object someId = 'someId'
        java.lang.Object event = new apackage.SomeEventObject()
        this.getSpecificationContext().getMockController().enterScope()
        this.getSpecificationContext().getMockController().addInteraction(new org.spockframework.mock.runtime.InteractionBuilder(25, 9, '1 * eventPublisher.publishEvent(new SomeNextEvent(updatedValue))').setFixedCount(1).addEqualTarget(eventPublisher).addEqualMethodName('publishEvent').setArgListKind(true, false).addEqualArg(new apackage.SomeNextEvent(updatedValue)).build())
        sut.handle(event)
        this.getSpecificationContext().getMockController().leaveScope()
        java.lang.Object updatedValue = myClassRepository.findTestClass(someId)
        try {
            org.spockframework.runtime.SpockRuntime.verifyCondition($spock_errorCollector, $spock_valueRecorder.reset(), 'updatedTestClass.cash == 100', 23, 13, null, $spock_valueRecorder.record($spock_valueRecorder.startRecordingValue(3), $spock_valueRecorder.record($spock_valueRecorder.startRecordingValue(1), $spock_valueRecorder.record($spock_valueRecorder.startRecordingValue(0), updatedTestClass).cash) == $spock_valueRecorder.record($spock_valueRecorder.startRecordingValue(2), 100)))
        }
        catch (java.lang.Throwable throwable) {
            org.spockframework.runtime.SpockRuntime.conditionFailedWithException($spock_errorCollector, $spock_valueRecorder, 'updatedTestClass.cash == 100', 23, 13, null, throwable)}
        finally {
        }
        this.getSpecificationContext().getMockController().leaveScope()
    }
```

If you look closely, you can see that the interaction definition was moved **before** the `when` block, but the `findTestClass()` call stayed behind.
that is why you get the missing property exception.

The solution is to either move the lookup to the `given` block, or if that is not possible, to use argument capturing and then check afterwards.

```
given:
def capturedEvent

when:
...

then:
1 * eventPublisher.publishEvent(_) >> { capturedEvent = it[0} }

and:

def updatedValue = myClassRepository.findTestClass(someId)
capturedEvent instanceof SomeNextEvent
capturedEvent.value == updatedValue
```

You can take a look at the transformed code yourself in the [groovy web console](https://gwc-experiment.appspot.com/?codez=eJxtUrFygzAM3f0VOiboQJK1d0y9Dh3S9kqvu2OL4JbYHDZJczn-vTamLphqkqWnpydZrKFaw_76jto8jD5-G5RcQ9kiE5Vg1Agl4UYIAWttJ87UoK3waN2bfxNv2CotjOqucIojEdXjGaV57Q-N0DV2gMtnAXvFvtJsKuJYQVLWqm84cAVandDUQh6TNLMaYbKjsCT34elss3FY4NTQRdwRuswTt60S7yUrxCjKAiReoLSYUfPL4ROZcdLm8Esdt7Y7ymsqeYPpyDMrMCuw69a3VibyD9r0aJuuFphXQvLwY6kXnS1oJooAyhnVNRQF7Lbbv_Y7uIv2nbfeGwdMf8d9tkfhI3NpmW85kIEQNt2Rv4rbsAzMriGkom8P8Wi9y0QQ4sLzeX8AEv7b-g) by clicking on `Inspect AST`.

Comment: Just because I wanted to play with the GWC for the first time and find out how easy or tedious it actually is to edit code there, I manually made Leonard's example successfully run the test by adding some methods, initialising some objects and fixing small bugs like correct spelling of `instanceof`. The updated code is [here](https://gwc-experiment.appspot.com/?gist=3d5f74a61ef3cc95e709aedc2f5e1ed2).